# Someone is spamming links to my site by 301 redirecting his domain to mine what should I do?

Tags: seo, redirects, google-search, spam, disavow-links

I have already disvowed the domain. Still he is creating more than 100k links daily.

How should I report this to Google?

Comment: Can you give us more information?? Is the whole site redirected or are they creating links and using a redirect script? It may make a difference in how to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, They are creating the links and using the redirect script. Before it was like 1000 links and after checking in the webmaster yesterday, the very same website pointing 100k+ links to mine. 

When I vistied the site, it's just showing the some php install page.

Comment: I re-read your question. Sorry. I was up all last night. I updated the answer with a thought at least.

Answer (score 1):

With so many links, you have no choice but to disavow them using the Google Disavow Links Tool. You will need a Google Search Console (webmaster tools) account to do this. You can get started using this page from Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

This should be a simple enough task and not too scary. You should be able to disavow links using the spammers domain name without having to specify all of the links.

Short of that, there is nothing you can do to let Google know directly that you are not pleased.

Indirectly, you can use your .htaccess or other similar method to break any referral from this site. In other words, if someone were to follow the link from the offending site, then they would get a 410, 404, or some other appropriate error. If someone were to follow a similar link from any other site, they would get the page. This technique has been used in the past, however, because it is rarely used mostly due to lack of knowledge, no-one can really say what the effect is. The message is fairly clear. Whether Google takes the hint is another story.